# C# - Set two attributes with displaymember in ListBox component

Tags: c#, listbox

I try to display "FirstName" and "LastName" attributes in my ListBox component on the same row like this "SMITH Robert" but when I launch the program, I have the Id attribute. The problem is probably that the program doesn't find the attributes "LastName" and "FirstName" ...

My Customer class :

```
public class Customer
{
    private int id;
    private string lastName;
    private string firstName;

    public Customer(int id, string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.lastName = lastName.ToUpper();
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    #region Accessors

    public int GetId() { return id; }
    public string GetLastName() { return lastName; }
    public string GetFirstName() { return firstName; }

    public void SetId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public void SetLastName(string lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
    public void SetFirstName(string firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value; } }
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value; } }

    #endregion
}
```

My function which I would to use for this manipulation (customers is a List of customers load from an *Access* database (this part work)):

```
// Define where is from data.
lbxCustomers.DataSource = customers;
// Value show in listbox.
lbxCustomers.DisplayMember = "LastNameFirstName";
// Value when row is selected in listbox.
lbxCustomers.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Comment: If you override `ToString()` in the class you can print what you want - just specify no `DisplayMember`. As Intellisense will tell you the `DisplayMember` is a *property name* and you have none named "LastNameFirstName"

Comment: LarsTech have gived a solution ... I think I will go to sleep, I'm probably tired because my question was very stupid ... Thx for your help!

Comment: There is a difference between the 2 answers/methods.  An explicit property will also show up in other bound controls like a DGV or prop grid which you may not want

Comment: I need only to use a listbox. DataGridView is not necessary in this project (thanks god!). I try tomorrow to override ToString() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the DisplayMember information to be an existing property in the referencing class:

```
public string LastNameFirstName {
  get {
    return lastName + ", " + firstName;
  }
}
```